# Cassandra prometheus integration

Tags: cassandra, monitoring, prometheus, criteo

I am using the JMX prometheus exporter for exporting Cassandra metrics using the java agent. Are there any performance issues that I need to be wary about?

Recently I came across https://github.com/criteo/cassandra_exporter.

Can you share your experience with managing Cassandra using Prometheus - specifically with respect to the exporter used?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Telegraf (from InfluxDB ecosystem) to expose Cassandra metrics to Prometheus.
Just add Jolokia to Cassandra to expose JMX metrics over http and then use JMX input and Prometheus output plugins in Telegraf.